# How my student access our courses in elearning odoo

Tags: odoo

In odoo elearning, I created many courses.But I have no idea how my student access my courses.They all need user account for accessing courses?

Answer (score 1):

Under the website settings, you can allow Free sign up for Customer Account. And then they can register to the courses.

Comment: When I login with customer account , I cant see my courses step.There is no step in my courses.What's wrong?@Paxmees

Comment: If you edit your course, under the Options tab there are Access Rights and Display sections. they should control that